# complex transform of pandas dataframe to generate new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This one's tough and beyond my pandas abilities. IF someone wants to take a shot at it I'd much appreciate it.I posted my code below. I got 80% there but the last but is tricky.

Basically I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Antimicrobial            Determinant  Frequency
0         anti1                  det1        0.8
1         anti1                  det1        0.5
2         anti1                  det2        0.5
3         anti2                  det3        0.9
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
  Antimicrobial            Determinant    Frequency
0         anti1            det1; det2    [0.8, 0.5]; 0.5
1         anti2                  det3            0.9
```

I want to:

1. groupby Antimicrobial column [done]
2. For each Antimicrobial join the list of sorted unique determinants together on semicolon [done]
3. have the list of frequencies joined together in same order as determinants [HELP]
4. And if multiple frequencies exist for the same determinant join them together on a comma and include in square brackets (order does not matter) [HELP]

Thanks !

Here's my code:

```
agg_fn = {
    "Determinant": lambda x: "; ".join(sorted(x.unique())),
    "Frequency": lambda x: "; ".join(x.astype(str)),
    #"Determinant with Frequency": lambda x: "; ".join(x.astype(str)),
}


df = pd.DataFrame({'Antimicrobial': ['anti1', 'anti1', 'anti1', 'anti2'], 'Determinant': ['det1', 'det1', 'det2', 'det3'], 'Frequency': [0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9]})

print("before agg")
print(df)

#df['Determinant'] = df['Genotypic Determinant'] + " (" + df['Frequency'].astype(str) + ")"
#df = df.drop("Genotypic Determinant", axis=1)
#df = df.drop("Frequency", axis=1)
df = df.groupby("Antimicrobial", as_index=False).agg(agg_fn)

print("after agg")
print(df)
```

I posted what I tried above

Comment: Mind if I ask _why_ you want to do this? This seems like a horrible idea from a memory perspective. Typically each entry of data is some primitive data type (e.g. int64). By making it a list, you force each entry to be an object dtype. As a result it is harder to manipulate and make use of.

Comment: These dataframes will always be small in size. Also the data fields don't need to be an object dtype they could be a string but the final df needs to look like what I posted above

Answer (score 0):

I would use a double [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), first with a custom function and the default `sort=True` to order the groups lexicographically, then with `'; '.join`:

```
def list_if_many(x):
    '''returns a list if several items else the item (as string)'''
    return str(list(x)) if len(x)>1 else str(x.squeeze())

out = (df.groupby(['Antimicrobial', 'Determinant'], as_index=False)
         .agg(list_if_many)
         .groupby('Antimicrobial', as_index=False, sort=False)
         .agg('; '.join)
      )
```

If you want to use a custom sorting order (e.g. natural sorting), first [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) then `groupby` with `sort=False`:

```
from natsort import natsort_key

def list_if_many(x):
    return str(list(x)) if len(x)>1 else str(x.squeeze())

out = (df.sort_values(by=['Antimicrobial', 'Determinant'], key=natsort_key)
         .groupby(['Antimicrobial', 'Determinant'], as_index=False, sort=False)
         .agg(list_if_many)
         .groupby('Antimicrobial', as_index=False, sort=False)
         .agg('; '.join)
      )
```

Output:

```
  Antimicrobial Determinant        Frequency
0         anti1  det1; det2  [0.8, 0.5]; 0.5
1         anti2        det3              0.9
```